# Codeigniter PHP checking

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

how can i writer checking code with different table.

if data already exist in table STAFF user are allow to edit only

else user allow to insert then after that edit permanently.

more explanation on code comment
hopefully can understand.thanks you master.

Controller

```
public function Test()
{

   $d['checking'] = $this->db->query("SELECT status,amount,br_loc FROM account");
   $d['test'] = $this->db->query("SELECT br_loc FROM staff");

    $this->load->view('Account/global/header');
    $this->load->view('test',$d);
    $this->load->view('Account/global/footer');
}
```

View

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Code</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    <?php
      foreach($checking as $c)
        {   
        foreach($data->result_array() as $row)  // data select from table ACCOUNT and show as array..From table ACCOUNt data will insert to table STAFF. 
        {       
        ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['br_loc'];?></td> <!--CHECKING -if data already insert in table staff show button edit else button save to insert-->
            <?php if($c['status'] == 'save')
            { ?>
            <td><button type="button" value ='Edit'  class="btn btn-primary" id="edit<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" >Edit</button></td>
             <?php  }
            else
            { ?>
            <td><button type="button" value ='Save'  class="btn btn-primary" id="save<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" >save</button></td>
           <?php  } ?>
          </tr>
         <?php
              }
            }
         ?>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Result

keep looping and duplicate.

[image]

Comment: You have nested loops, that's why it happens

Comment: This is weird, you use sql on the controller. I will load a model, and return sql query result(It a array) to controller, and set as view's parameter.

Comment: yes that the CI MVC should did

Answer (score 0):

unless i am missing something but i think your loop is wrong

you set your querys in the controller but in the view you are not reaching out to the result....

to do this
$checking->result_array()
$test->result_array()

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Code</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
    foreach($test->result_array() as $row)  // data select from table ACCOUNT and show as array..From table ACCOUNt data will insert to table STAFF. 
    {       
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['br_loc'];?></td> <!--CHECKING -if data already insert in table staff show button edit else button save to insert-->
        <?php 
        $tempStatus = null;
        foreach($checking->result_array() as $c){
            if($c['br_loc'] == $row['br_loc']){
                $tempStatus = $c['status'];
            }
        }
        if($tempStatus == 'save')
        { ?>
        <td><button type="button" value ='Edit'  class="btn btn-primary" id="edit<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" >Edit</button></td>
         <?php  }
        else
        { ?>
        <td><button type="button" value ='Save'  class="btn btn-primary" id="save<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" >save</button></td>
       <?php  } ?>
      </tr>
     <?php
          }
    ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

so im guess is you want something like this?
also for codeigniter I would recommend the template plugin it will make your life alot easier instead of having to load tons of views.

Comment: sorry that was a bad answer i changed it now. the comments in your post are right your first foreach loop is not at the right place. its a bit difficult to test it here since i dont have the data in your database but something like this should work

Comment: thank you.code is working and i get your idea to make modification